# How do I set a default view on the rally userstories page

Tags: rally

When using rally on the default user stories page, how do I set the default view?

I have a custom view and I want that to open automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create or edit the custom view there is an option 'Set as Default' located right under the part of the form you use to set the display columns. Note: this will only set the view as the default view for your login and even for your account it will only set the view as the default view for the Plan -> User Stories page.

[image: Edit Custom View Form]